# Do (some) netbooks not have Hibernate even as an optional setting under Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, hibernate, netbook

I recently bought my third netbook. This one is a Lenovo Ideapad 100S that came with Windows 10.

This setup does not include "Hibernate" as a possibility along with "Sleep", "Shut down", and "Restart".

[I found an article online that says "Hibernate" is now an option that you have to enable and has instructions on how to do so.](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-hibernate-mode-windows-10/)

But when I follow these instructions I do not get the new Hibernate option as illustrated. This is the dialog on my system after following the instructions:

[image: Windows 10 Shutdown settings]

My previous netbook was a HP Mini that came with Windows 7. In most ways that netbook was a little less powerful than the new netbook. Yet it still allowed me to user Hibernate even with a small internal drive and even with its RAM upgraded to the maximum possible 2G.

Is this a new limitation imposed upon netbooks by Microsoft? Or is there some reason it's not possible on this particular netbook? Or is there some extra step required to enable it on an Ideapad 100S?

Comment: What happens if you run `powercfg -h on` from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: I couldn't find this before, but now that i've posted my question I find [a previous related question](https://superuser.com/questions/950864) but I'm not sure yet whether mine is a duplicate or not ...

Comment: @Jonno: The command completes with no output. My shutdown menu has not changed...

Comment: Can you check if you have `Intel Rapid Start` on your machine, possibly an entry in the `Control Panel` or `Programs and Features`?

Comment: @Jonno: I can't seem to find `Intel Rapid Start` in either the Control pan or Programs and Features.

Comment: Hmm, my only other thought is, after running the command in my first comment, try rebooting and check the first menu you tried again, and checking under power plan options to see if it has a `hibernate` section like I have here: http://i.imgur.com/Xl8bNAE.jpg

Comment: I can't reboot just yet as I'm asking about this problem in the background as I do some more important work. But my power plan options at this point doesn't even have a Sleep section! http://i.stack.imgur.com/NhoyM.png

Comment: following @Jonno method, look at the hibernate option under `Power buttons and lid \ Lid close action \ On battery` (or any other option). If you don't have it, try to update your display adapter.

Comment: Which power (restart, shutdown ..) options do you see when you press Alt + F4 in Desktop or right clicking to bottom left windows icon?

Comment: @ek.bic: I have: Switch user, Sign out, Sleep, Shut down, and Restart.

Comment: @Sanny: All options offer only: Do nothing, Sleep, Shut down.

Comment: Why do you need Hibernation anymore? I see you already have Fast Startup turned on. From what I knew they are basically the same thing (S4 stage sleep). To truly turn off a PC with Fast Startup, you must use Restart.

Comment: @Vassile: This setup also has a problem where it often BSOD's when using `Sleep` so I thought I would go with `Hibernate` until that problem is sorted out. I often like to leave everything open when I'm away so that I don't have to open everything back up and position all the windows etc every time I come back.

Comment: @hippietrail Never mind. Even though FS is using hibernation behind the scene but it closes all programs and returns PC to a fresh state "just like a cold boot". My bad.

Comment: @Jonno: `powercfg -h on` + reboot did in fact add Hibernate as an advanced option to the power plans dialog. [ek.bic](http://superuser.com/users/561201/ek-bic) submitted that sequence [as an answer](http://superuser.com/a/1043883/58110) so I guess I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm glad I helped

Comment: Lol... Mine hibernates, shuts off the screen, and then I can't wake it up. I need to press and hold the power button for 10 seconds to reboot it.... Lenovo does have an updated ACPI Power driver on their site for the netbook. I've been running with it, so buyer beware...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, right click to the Windows icon on the bottom left part of the screen, then go click run cmd as administrator. Then type in ( to cmd ) 'powercfg -h on' without the 's and press enter.

Then restart your PC and check the advanced power settings, feel free to ask anything anyway

Comment: The command runs with no error message or any other output.

After restarting the advanced power settings did let me add the hibernate function and I have tested that it works. (Though unlike my previous laptops the screen goes blank straight away.)

Comment: Haha wow I'm not sure that will work though 

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the plan settings for your power plan. Under `Power Options` choose the plan, click on `Change plan settings` or something similar, from there `Change advanced power settings` and finally you should be able to scroll down to `Hibernate`.

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnbfVFqkKOA) for clarifications - though for Windows 7, the settings are pretty similar. It's a roughly twelve minutes video, but the power plan settings are explained at 5:47 and the next few minutes.

Comment: My dialog doesn't have any `Hibernate`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NhoyM.png

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that, wasn't clear from your question. If you prefer, I can delete this answer, and you can edit your question to include the new screenshot picture.

Comment: Yes I didn't know at the beginning either. I got that far by following Jonno's comments to the question.

Comment: Did you try the steps in the linked question http://superuser.com/questions/950864/windows-10-hibernation-not-available?lq=1 This: `powercfg -h -size 75%`

Comment: The command succeeded. I'll let you know if it made Hibernate available after my next reboot. I have some work ongoing on this machine for now before I can do that.

Comment: I now have a Hibernate option but I'm not sure if it was due to the plain `powercfg -h on` as suggested by a couple of people or due to this `powercfg -h -size 75%`.

Comment: Got it, glad you solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows 10 I did not find any options to enable **Hibernate** as an option, but I did find something good enough.

Under `Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Power Options`, then there's **"Change plan settings**" (mentioned in other answers).

From there, "**Change advanced power settings**" (possibly reachable via other routes).

In there, there's "**+Battery**" which I expanded to to find "**+Critical Battery Action**". Mine was already set to "Hibernate" but what I did was to then change "**+Critical battery level**" to 10% from 5% thinking maybe my machine had previously (the time it didn't hibernate properly) died while trying to hibernate.

After these steps, my machine seems to have hibernated properly over night.